# Downgrading from 64-bit Windows to 32-bit Windows

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, reinstall, 32-vs-64-bit

I currently have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit installed on my laptop. For a long time I've been having lots of problems with my laptop, such as:

- Getting the message, "Consider Replacing Your battery".
- Laptop working really slow when on very low charge or when overcharging.
- Low battery life of the laptop - just 1 and half hour.
- Laptop Getting "Hibernate" when I actually gave the option of "Sleep" or "Lock"
- Generally, the system works slow and the programs gets, "Not Responding" all the time.

I have tried reinstalling Windows, but it didn't help at all. Will my grievances diminish if I install a 32-bit version of Windows instead of the current 64-bit, as less of the CPU's capacity/resource will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get all the indicators served to you:

***The battery is dying, get it replaced.***

If that doesn't work, there might be other faulty hardware and you should have your whole laptop replaced instead. You can also check this by removing the battery and just running on current. If the behavior is very different, it's your battery. If the behavior stays, there might be some other problems.

Changing from a 64 bit to a 32 bit will actually result in getting less resources for the OS. (less memory).

Comment: okay, i will try running on only current and observe the behavior for a few days.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds much more like a battery problem. Notice how all the messages seem to have something to do with power? Hibernating instead of sleeping would be automatically activated by a low battery, and obviously, a bad battery would be the cause of "Consider replacing your battery" messages.

So, buy a new one, replace it, and see what happens.

---

Side note:

> as less of the CPU's capacity/resource will be used?

No. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Does the system work better when plugged in?

Comment: @uSlackr I think so, but the problem with replacing battery is that it's would consume a few days - may be upto a month.

Comment: @RishabhPoddar: Then that's how long you'll have to wait. Moving to 32-bit won't help with a battery problem. Nothing much will, actually, short of replacing the battery or just staying plugged in.